# Inexpressiblity of a group having an element of infinite order

Tags: group-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L} = \{ e, \cdot \}$ be the first-order language of groups.

I want to show that the property of a group having an element of infinite order is inexpressible in $\mathcal{L}$. I haven't found such a result anywhere so I don't even know if its true, so just wanted a quick check whether the proof I've written is correct.

$\space$
$\space$

Let $\mathcal{L}^+$ be the first-order language obtained by appending a single constant symbol $c$ to $\mathcal{L}$, and let $\Phi$ be $\mathcal{L}$-sentences consisting of the group axioms. Suppose for contradiction that $\varphi$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence expressing the property of a group having an element of infinite order.

Let $\psi_n$ be the $\mathcal{L}^+$-sentence $c^n \ne e$ for $n \ge 1$. Then clearly, a model of $\Phi \cup \{ \psi \mid n \ge 1 \}$ is group which has an element of infinite order, namely whatever the symbol $c$ refers to. Hence, $\Phi \cup \{ \psi \mid n \ge 1 \} \models \varphi$.

By the compactness theorem, there is $N \ge 1$ such that $\Phi \cup \{ \psi_1, \psi_2, \cdots, \psi_N \} \models \varphi$. That is to say, every group that has an element whose first $N$ positive powers are not the identity has an element of infinite order. This is clearly absurd: simply consider the group $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ for any prime $p > N$ as a counterexample.

We conclude that no such $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ can exist so that the property of a group having an element of infinite order is inexpressible in $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: It looks correct